# jQuery append div after an input with specific name?

Tags: jquery, append

I have the following HTML

```
<input type="submit" name="cm-ajax-submit" value="Register">
```

I need to append a div tag so it'll have this format

`<input type="submit" name="cm-ajax-submit" value="Register"><div id="cmprivacy"></div>`

Is there a way to use jQuery append or another function to find the input with the name cm-ajax-submit and append that div?

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Create the element and move it using `.after`,

```
$('input[name=cm-ajax-submit]').after('<div id="cmprivacy"></div>');
```

Answer (score 6):

Use the [`.after`](http://api.jquery.com/after/) function, not `.append`.

html:

```
<input id="button" type="submit" name="cm-ajax-submit" value="Register">​
```

jQuery:

```
$('#button').click(function() {
    $(this).after('<div id="cmprivacy">Hey</div>');
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sfsWC/

Answer (score 2):

Try this.. Use .after() method

```
$('input[name="cm-ajax-submit"]').after('<div id="cmprivacy"></div>')
```